# spring maven project upgrade to 11

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-orm

I have a maven java project. The SDK was java 8, now i want to upgrade to java 11. I also want to upgrade all the dependencies to the latest ones. It is a spring project (not spring-boot!!)

I could resolve all different upgrade issues, however there is an error in entity manager factory to set the persistence provider class.

```
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  @DependsOn("flyway")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
...
}
```

the `HibernatePersistenceProvider.class` implements the `jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`

however the `setPersistenceProviderClass` method requires a class of `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`

i have

```
<org.springframework.version>5.3.19</org.springframework.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

there is one more strange thing to me. in IntelliJ when i open the class of `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean` it says bytecode version is java 8, but `HibernatePersistenceProvider` is java 11

Comment: Hibernate 6.0 was released about a month ago, spring framework does not yet support it

Answer (score 0):

According to this [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.6.4) information, your used

`spring-orm verion` of `5.3.19` comes with `spring-data-jpa` of version `2.6.4` which then is bundled with the dependency of `hibernate-core` where the supported version to be used is `5.6.0.Final`.

Also according to the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html)

> Version 5.3.19
>
> As of Spring Framework 5.1, Spring requires JDK 8+
> (Java SE 8+) and provides **out-of-the-box support for JDK 11 LTS**

So according to that maven repo documentation and spring documentation the version that should be used is `hibernate-core`  `5.6.0.Final`.

Keep in mind that java is backwards compatible, which means that a project compiled with a previous `JDK` will most times be able to run in a newer `JDK` except when some structural components have been affected and for that reason you need to inspect the [oracle migration documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-7744EF96-5899-4FB2-B34E-86D49B2E89B6) to see where you stand.

But for the specific issue that you mention here and your concern I would go with the documentation which mentions to use the `hibernate-core` `5.6.0.Final`, according to which you should not expect any problems with `JDK 11`.

Comment: > of hibernate-core where the supported versions are from 5.6.0.Final up to 6.0.1.Final - "Updates" means something different :)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov you are right, I have mistaken the updates column in maven repo. Just edited the answer.